# Using SQL - How to aggregate Payment Type

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I aggregate the PaymentType field so that if a customer has used all payment types previously, the payment type screen displays 'All' instead of 'Cash', 'Check', 'Credit/Debit Card', or 'Corporate Account'? Below is the script necessary to demonstrate the issue.

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE #Customer (
    CustomerId int,
    CustomerName nvarchar(100),
    Address nvarchar(100),
)
INSERT INTO #Customer
VALUES (1, 'Bill', '123 1st St'),
       (2, 'Fred', '111 Market St'),
       (3, 'Lisa', '01 Boulevard')

CREATE TABLE #Product (
    ProductId int,
    ProductName nvarchar(100)
)
INSERT INTO #Product
VALUES (1, 'Corn Flakes'),
       (2, 'Cheerios'),
       (3, 'Granoloa')

CREATE TABLE #PaymentType (
    PaymentId int,
    PaymentTypeName nvarchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO #PaymentType
VALUES (1, 'Cash'),
       (2, 'Check'),
       (3, 'Credit/Debit Card'),
       (4, 'Corporate Account')

CREATE TABLE #TransactionLog (
    LogId int,
    ProductId int,
    CustomerId int,
    PaymentId int,
    Amount float
)
INSERT INTO #TransactionLog
VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1, 2.00),
       (2, 2, 1, 2, 2.40),
       (3, 3, 1, 3, 1.80),
       (4, 1, 1, 4, 2.00),
       (5, 1, 2, 4, 2.00),
       (6, 2, 3, 2, 2.40)

SELECT * from #Customer
SELECT * from #Product
SELECT * from #PaymentType
SELECT * from #TransactionLog

SELECT
    c.CustomerName,
    p.ProductName,
    pt.PaymentTypeName as PaymentType
FROM #TransactionLog t
join #Product p on t.ProductId = p.ProductId
join #Customer c on t.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
join #PaymentType pt on t.PaymentId = pt.PaymentId

DROP TABLE #Customer
DROP TABLE #Product
DROP TABLE #PaymentType
DROP TABLE #TransactionLog
```

Comment: What happens if they haven't used all the payment types? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will work. You might need to tune it if you have a lot of data or an underpowered database instance though.

```sql
;WITH
Data AS(
    SELECT
        c.CustomerName,
        p.ProductName,
        pt.PaymentTypeName as PaymentType
    FROM #TransactionLog t
    join #Product p on t.ProductId = p.ProductId
    join #Customer c on t.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
    join #PaymentType pt on t.PaymentId = pt.PaymentId
)
SELECT DISTINCT
    d.CustomerName,
    d.ProductName,
    PaymentType = IIF( ( (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sd.PaymentType) FROM Data sd WHERE sd.CustomerName = d.CustomerName) = 4), 
                    'All', 
                    d.PaymentType
                )
FROM
    Data d
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select CustomerName,case when count(distinct(PaymentType)) = 4 then 'All' end as PaymentType from (SELECT
    c.CustomerName,
    p.ProductName,
    pt.PaymentTypeName as PaymentType
FROM #TransactionLog t
join #Product p on t.ProductId = p.ProductId
join #Customer c on t.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
join #PaymentType pt on t.PaymentId = pt.PaymentId )
group by CustomerName
```

This is one way of doing this you can tweak it as per your need.